# ¿Como cambiar una imagen al actualizar la página, con su respectivo link?

Tags: javascript, html

Holaa, bueno, tengo una página dónde tengo que mostrar publicidad, y quiero que cada vez que se actualice la página, cambie la imágen de la publicidad, pero  tengo un pequeño problema. Lo que ya pude hacer es que las imagenes cambien al azar cada vez que se actualiza la página. Mi problema es que el link que te llevará a la página correspondiente e de la publicidad no funciona correctamente, no va con la imagen en correspondiente. ¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar?:c

### Código de HTML

```
<aside>
<blockquote id="text-ads">Publicidad</blockquote>   
<a href="https://www.coca-cola.com.mx" id="link" target="_blank"><img src="publicidad/coca-banner.jpg" alt="Publicidad no disponible" class="advertising" id="ia"></a>
</aside>
```

### Codigo de JavaScript

```
function rand(n){
// Numero al azar entre 1 y 10
 return(Math.floor(Math.random() * n + 1 ));
}
//Array de imagenes
var cambia_imagen = new Array();
cambia_imagen[0] = "publicidad/coca-banner.jpg";
cambia_imagen[1] = "publicidad/redmik20-banner.jpg";
cambia_imagen[2] = "publicidad/redminote8-banner.jpg";
cambia_imagen[3] = "publicidad/hp-banner.jpg";
cambia_imagen[4] = "publicidad/doritos-banner.jpg";
cambia_imagen[5] = "publicidad/logitech-banner.jpg";
cambia_imagen[6] = "publicidad/sony-xb-banner.jpg";
cambia_imagen[7] = "publicidad/totalplay-banner.jpg";
cambia_imagen[8] = "publicidad/kz-banner.jpg";
cambia_imagen[9] = "publicidad/kzs2-banner.jpg";

var cambia_link = new Array();
cambia_link[0] = "https://www.coca-cola.com.mx";
cambia_link[1] = "https://mi-globe.com/xiaomi-is-said-to-work-on-a-redmi-featuring-64-mp-camera/redmi-k20-banner/";
cambia_link[2] = "https://computerhoy.com/listas/tecnologia/5-motivos-comprar-xiaomi-redmi-note-8-pro-merece-pena-508269";
cambia_link[3] = "https://www8.hp.com/mx/es/home.html";
cambia_link[4] = "https://doritos.es";
cambia_link[5] = "https://www.logitech.com/es-mx";
cambia_link[6] = "https://www.sony.com.mx/electronics/bocinas-inalambricas/srs-xb12";
cambia_link[7] = "https://www.totalplay.com.mx";
cambia_link[8] = "https://kzstoremexico.com.mx";
cambia_link[9] = "https://kzstoremexico.com.mx";
function cambiar(){
     document.getElementById("ia").src = cambia_imagen[rand(10)-1]; cambia_imagen=cambia_link;
     document.getElementById("link").href = cambia_link[rand(10)-1];
}

window.addEventListener("load", cambiar, false);
```

Espero puedan ayudarme :C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás generando 2 números aleatorios, por lo que no siempre van a coincidir, en el primero te puede salir 5 y en el segundo 2, entonces mostrará la imagen 5 pero con el link 2.

Para solucionarlo solo genera un único número aleatorio y ese usa para ambas asignaciones

```
let numero_aleatorio = rand(10)-1
document.getElementById("ia").src = cambia_imagen[numero_aleatorio]; cambia_imagen=cambia_link;
document.getElementById("link").href = cambia_link[numero_aleatorio];
```

Comment: Muchas gracias brooo. Me sirvió <3